# How to set image as the source of camera

Tags: java, android, image, camera

I wanna know if there is any way that I can use an image as the camera source to trick the in-app camera shooting of other apps, it doesn't matter if this needs root or Xposed or etc. thank you in advance

Comment: In the nutshell, you can hook the Binder to achieve this.